# How can I show that $X=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^d a_kt^k:~d\geq 0,a_k\in \Bbb{R}\right\}$ is not complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, baire-category

> Let $X$ be a vector space of real polynomials, $$X=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^d a_kt^k:~d\geq 0,a_k\in \Bbb{R}\right\}$$I want to show that $X$ is not compleate with respect to any norm on $X$.

My idea was to use the Baire-Category theorem:

> Let $X$ be a complete metric space, $A_n\subset X$ closed subsets such that $A_n^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$ then $\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right)^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$.

**Proof** Let us assume there exists a norm such that $X$ is a complete normed space w.r.t. this norm. Let $$X_d=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^d a_kt^k:~a_k\in \Bbb{R}\right\}$$ then since $X_d$ is finite dimensional we know in particular that it is closed for all $d$. Furthermore $$X=\bigcup_{d=0}^\infty X_d$$

> We know that if $Y\subset X$ is a subspace of a normed space $X$, then $X\setminus Y$ is dense in $X$.

Using this we remark that $X\setminus X_d$ is dense in $X$ for all $d$ but this means that $X_d$ is nowhere dense in $X$, i.e. for all $d$, $X_d^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$. Applying the Baire-Category theorem we deduce that $$X^{\mathrm{o}}=\left(\bigcup_{d=0}^\infty X_d\right)^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$$

Now I don't know if $X^{\mathrm{o}}=X$ if it would be we would have a contradiction, otherwise I don't see how to conclude. Can maybe someone help me?

Comment: Any metric space $X$ satisfies $X^o = X$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. and why?

Comment: Let me ask you: what is the definition of the interior of a subset $A \subset X$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. It would be the largest open set contained in $A$ so the union of all open sets which are contained in $A$

Comment: For each $x \in X$ take $B(x,r) = \{y \in X : \|x-y\| < r\}$. Is it the case that $$X = \bigcup_{x \in X} B(x,1)?$$

Comment: @UmbertoP. Hmm I think we only know $\subseteq$

Comment: But each $B(x,1) \subseteq X$ too.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Ah yes sorry, your right.

Comment: @UmbertoP. And so $X$ is open and hence $X^o = X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, any normed vector space which has a countable basis is not complete. Suppose $(e_i)_{i\geqslant 0}$ is such a basis (here you can take $e_i=X^i$) and let $X_i=\operatorname{Span}(e_0,\ldots,e_i)$ so that
$$ X=\bigcup_{i\geqslant 0}X_i. $$
Now, each $X_i$ is a strict vector subspace of $X$ thus $\mathring{X_i}=\emptyset$ and, each $X_i$ is a finite dimensional vector space and therefore is closed in $X$. By Baire theorem, if $X$ were complete, then we would have $\mathring{X}=\emptyset$ (I'm doing the same thing as you wrote). The contradiction is that, as you guessed, $\mathring{X}=X$ : this is trivial because $X$ is open !

Comment: Sorry why is in my case $X$ open?

Comment: By basis, I assume you mean that every element of $X$ can be represented as a linear combination of finitely many $e_i$'s, otherwise any separable Hilbert space with its orthonormal basis will be a counterexample.

Comment: @fwd Yes that's what I meant by an infinite basis.

Comment: @user1294729 Any topological space $X$ is itself open by definition of a topology. Since you have a normed vector space, you could also say that for any $x\in X$, any open ball containing $x$ is inside $X$ so it is open, this is a tautology !

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable basis and is complete?

Comment: By countable I mean in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, so a finite set is not countable.